# Android Studio make module as both Application and Library?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

i am a newer in Android Studio and was amazed by Gradle.
I found out there could be more possibility as Eclipse.
I understand the different of apply plugin: 'com.android.application' and 'com.android.library'
What i wonder is: exist some way to set the module as Android Application and Android Library Project at same time?
I have a Library Project "MyLibrary" in android studio, with many library module, for example mylib1, mylib2,.....
My other Android Project/Module could use these Library.
If i could build Sample Activity in the same module and let the IDE decide when is to launch as app, when is as lib, the project structure will be somehow "cleaner", better than mylib1 + mylib1sample.

Please excuse my poor english and thanks for any idea!

Comment: you just can't launch a library.

Comment: I feel it is quite a pity, for the only different i see is the "com.android.library/application". As a IDE, make a module in 2 different build version and launch/reference the right one should not be a difficult deal -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in short: no.
But you could write a wrapping application that just utilizes the library. This is what I do when testing libraries in android (utilizing the library and unit test the wrapping application).

responding to the comment:
Make a new module as android.application, add the library as dependency
like

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':thelibrary')
}
```

add an activity to the app module, that just starts the library activity via Intent.

Comment: I am quite a newbie in android-studio/gradle. could you please tell me some more detail? like screenshots/setting-files of your project structure ? :D

Comment: Added some additional info to the answer.

Comment: That is what i have to do now. Hope one day sth can be different in android studio!

Comment: Maybe some day. I stumbled upon this too, but now I feel pretty comfy with this approach.
please mark your questioned answered if you feel so.